# C++11 May 2012 status?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reviewing some of the posts on C++11 (originally C++0x). All the answers regarding compiler compatibility, resource availability and IDE support seemed fuzzy. Most of the posts were a year old.

I want to learn C++11 and I can't seem to find any resources for it. No books, No compilers, no IDE plugins nothing.

Can someone please tell me the latest status on C++11? I'm anxious regarding C++0x, since I read some of the specifications and it looked very intriguing. I think C++11 is more like Python with built in support for more exotic containers like tuples and dictionaries.

Comment: C++ has had tuples and hash tables since 2005 (TR1).

Comment: Dictionaries (a.k.a. hash tables) too.

Comment: What is (TR1)? I know I can emulate a hash table using maps, but how do I represent tuples ? I think, since C++ doesn't have a super global class (object), polymorphism doesn't allow me to store anything anywhere. This is (and has been) a major problem in C++. Normally, when you think of tuples, you think of a list of arbitrary objects, which If I try to emulate with a vector of references, I will be constraining myself to a specific inheritance tree. In java, though, I can use ArrayList of Object type and store four different type objects in a 4 length Arraylist to emulate a tuple.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: Typing system and tuples have nothing to do with each other. You won't get far wanting an orgasm of pointless runtime dispatch in C++, and tuples are no exception to this rule- C++ is a statically typed language at heart, and it's tuple support is no different. C++ tuples means a statically known number of statically known types- e.g. `tuple<int, int, int>`. However, you could look into libs like `boost::any` and `boost::optional`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to learn C++11 and I can't seem to find any resources for it.
>   No books, No compilers, no IDE plugins nothing.

That's most strange, because if you just [search "C++0x"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=C%2B%2B0x&ac=8) on the documentation site for the most popular compiler, Visual Studio, you will get a bunch of results on not only what features they support, but basic tutorials on how to use them.

The [Clang feature chart](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) is updated for Clang 3.1, 22nd May this year, which is what, 2 weeks ago?

The [GCC feature chart](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) was April this year.

Both GCC and Clang support the vast majority, if not virtually all, C++11 features, although there are yet some library and especially concurrency to be added.

Many book authors are still updating for C++11, because there's a lot to be said, and I admit that I know of few tutorials for the new features except those shown on MSDN. However, the compiler front, in general, is advancing it's C++11 support *extremely* rapidly.

In addition, some of the library features you mention, like tuples and hash maps,have actually been around for a long time- possibly even pre C++03 in the pseudo-Standard Boost library, and then in TR1.

Of course, it's worth noticing that neither Clang nor GCC have particularly good Windows support- to be generous- and Visual Studio is significantly lagging behind (although still some very important C++11 features to be found there, as well as the PPL and AMP). This means that there are few options for e.g. variadic templates on Windows.

Comment: I didn't know about CLang or TR1, and the kind of support I was talking about was the kind, where C++11 will be pre-shipped in my Linux distro or through a standard Cygwin installation. The problem with C++ has been lack of documentation for third party libraries. Even, to this day I haven't been able to find a good Boost primer. There have been excellent books on C++ (Meyers, Lippman, Josutitis etc.) but none on these extensions.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: Where C++11 is shipped in your distro? Just upgrade your damn compiler. It's not a core part of your OS. In addition, that depends on how new your distro is- the newer distros do indeed come with such things, including the newest Mac. Also, Boost is *exceptionally* well documented. You don't need a paper book- their site includes tutorials and reference for all their sublibraries. And if you have a problem that's solved by Boost, then just ask here- you will get pointed to the appropriate lib very quickly.